# When a component re-renders, are all variables inside it re-defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The question applies for both Class and function based components.
This is probably an way too easy question, but for some reason I can't find a concise definite answer so I sometimes get thrown off. All I can find is 'the component re-renders' but what does it actually mean? rendering is re-examine the state of the component to describe how to paint the DOM, but does it also re-define any referenced data-types within the component? Or will it only re-invoke the render() method on Class component?

In the functional component. Does it mean 'languages' array, 'updateLanguage' function, and everything I might put in is  re-defined? Or only what is defined in the return body? (like inline arrow handlers, etc...). I know we can use useCallback to prevent re-renders for stuff like handlers, but that is a different question.

```
const App = () => {
    const [selectedLang, setSelectedLang] = useState('');
    const languages = ['All', 'JavaScript', 'Ruby', 'Java',  'Python'];
    const updateLanguage = lang => setSelectedLang(lang);
    console.count('render');
    return (
        <ul>
            {languages.map(lang=> (
                <li key={lang}>
                    <button
                        className={`${selectedLang == lang && 'btn-selected'}`}
                        onClick={() => updateLanguage(lang)}
                        >
                        {lang}
                    </button>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
};
```

and with this Class based example, all of the instance methods will be re-defined on every render? or only stuff inside render() method?

```
class Languages extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {selectedLanguage: 'All'};
        this.updateLanguage = this.updateLanguage.bind(this);
    }
    updateLanguage(lang){
        this.setState({selectedLanguage: lang});
    }
    render(){
        const languages = ['All', 'JavaScript', 'Ruby', 'Java', 'Python'];
        const {selectedLanguage: selected} = this.state;
        console.count('render');
        return (
            <ul>
                {languages.map(lang=> (
                    <li key={lang}>
                        <button
                            className={`${selected == lang && 'selected'}`}
                            onClick={() => this.updateLanguage(lang)}
                            >
                            {lang}
                        </button>
                    </li>)
                )}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the functional component, consider the function *is* the render function. So it gets executed entirely like any normal function (no black magic here) on re-render. So yes, anything defined within that scope will be redefined.

With classes, the class members are initialized once. The constructor is not going to be called on re-render. The render method, of course, will be called.

Comment: By class members, do you mean instance methods?

Answer (score 1):

React docs state that

> Variables and event handlers don’t “survive” re-renders. Every render has its own event handlers.

State is a snapshot that is stored outside of a component, in React itself. All other variables are scoped to the component. And when it re-renders, all the variables in it are re-defined.

You can also observe this when value of a `const` variable changes during re-rendering of same component.

Refer [State as a Snapshot](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/state-as-a-snapshot) for better understanding.